# How can I move to a new line the last word of a <h1> sentence on mobile, and in desktop mode break the sentence in 3 lines?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

[image]

I have a mockup the designer gave me, and I have to mimic it using HTML and CSS. There's an  title that must look like this in desktop:

> Grow your
>
> business
>
> faster

, and in mobile, it must look like:

> Grow your business
>
> faster

I haven't been able to figure out the way to do this.

Can you give me a clue?

Thanks.

I have tried with word-break, but haven't been successful yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `<br>` tag in a `<span>` for which you set up a CSS rule and a media query showing/hiding it:

```css
.a {
 display: none;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
 .a {
  display: inline;
 }
}
```

```html
<h1>Grow your <span class="a"><br></span>business<br>faster</h1>
```

Comment: Why not apply the class to the `<br>` directly?

Answer (score 1):

**Try This**

```
<style>
      @media screen and (max-width: 467px){
          .newline{
               display:block;
                    }
                      }
          </style>
    <p>Grow your <span class="newline">business</span></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

The word-break property specifies **how words should break** when reaching the end of a line.

You could use a combination of HTML and CSS

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #title span {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="title">
  Grow your <span>business</span>
</div>
```